PlotlyJS 'scatter3D' not working outside ng serve
I basically have two Plotly-charts, one 'scattergl' and one 'scatter3d'.
If I am using ng serve everything works fine and both charts are shown perfectly. The trouble begins if I use ng build and serve the static assets:

Of course, my browser supports WebGL. I suspect Angulars bundle-process. I do import and use PlotlyJS like an ES6 module:
import Plotly, { Data } from 'plotly.js-dist-min';

As you cans ee I am using the minified version in my package.json:
"plotly.js-dist-min": "^2.35.2",

Even adding it as a CommonJS dependency or asset doesn't work at all:
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
  "plotly.js-dist-min"
],

Still the same picture. Is there any "trick"?

For my concrete problem, I could solve the issue by "just switching" to esbuild:
-      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
+      "executor": "@nx/angular:browser-esbuild",

While I don't understand the underlying issue completely, I am fine with "the fix".
